# Trim the end of binary XMLHttpRequest response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `XMLHttpRequest` code:

```
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

req.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (req.readyState != 4) return;
  if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
    alert('HTTP Error ' + req.status);
    return;
  }

  // check the end of response for "Error:(0|1)" and remove it if match found

  blob = new Blob([req.response], {type: "audio/mpeg"});
  saveAs(blob, "test.mp3");
}
```

But content sent from server may contain at the end of this **binary** file 7-character additional status message "`Error:(0|1)`", which I need to check and if found, removed before assigned to a blob, as shown above in my code.

What is the most efficient way to get and remove this status message, if present?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: You sure it's a string?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Regex with binary data?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: @Ωmega didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `slice` method of the buffers and the `String.fromCharCode` to get your string:

```
var end = new Uint8Array(req.response.slice(-7));
var endStr = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, end);
if (endStr == "Error:1")
    throw new Error("some problems");

var res = [endStr == "Error:0" ? req.response.slice(0, -7) : req.response];
var blob = new Blob(res, {type: "audio/mpeg"});
```

Comment: If error status is not present, then `fromCharCode` will deal with raw binary data and it may lead to error due to illegal encoding characters. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Ωmega I suspect it is not possible to get `String.fromCharCode` to throw an error. Maybe in certain browsers it might? I've been throwing lots of numbers (and other stuff) into it for a while without any problems.

Comment: @Ωmega In fact, here's a fiddle that demonstrates it's fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qhfGL/. I create a `Uint8Array` with all valid 8-byte unsigned values and toss it into `fromCharCode`.

Comment: I don't think it'll throw an error. The only think I'm not sure about is whether all browsers handle `\u0000` without problems (but I guess those that support ArrayBuffers do). If you really fear it, you probably have to compare the single `[69, 114, 114, 111, 114, 58, 48]` numbers against those from the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`Blob` objects have a method called `slice()`.

I would do an slice for last 11 bytes (that status message is 11 bytes long), save it on a var and check if that var equals to "`Error:(0|1)`", if it does, then I would use slice again to remove the 11 bytes.

Comment: Status message is 7 bytes long (if present), as it is `Error:0` or `Error:1`.

Comment: Well, slice the last 7 bytes instead of 11 then.

Comment: It is not an issue, 7 versus 11, that was just FYI. The issue here is how to compare such slice with string

Comment: Ok, maybe converting the Blob to a FileReader. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/TEnj9/1/ `reader.result` will contain the content as string